# Google docstrings in Python class

Tags: python, class, mixins, docstring

What's the correct way make google-style docstrings with private attributes in a class?

I have this code for example:

```
class IDMixin:
    """A mixin class generates unique IDs and account numbers for objects that inherit from it.

    Attributes:
        _ids (set): A set to store generated IDs.
        _accounts (set): A set to store generated account numbers.
    """
    _ids = set()
    _accounts = set()
```

Is that it? Sorry if this question is dumb but I want to make sure I'm doing it okay

Comment: Depends on what you are documenting: the class's interface or the class's implementation.